# How to use inline function in Cython

Tags: python, pointers, inline, cython

I am new in Cython and I have a problem compiling an inline function. The simplified code is:

```
cdef inline REG8(ulong addr):
   (<volatile_uchar_ptr *>(addr))[0]
```

I am trying to use the inline function inside a Python method:

```
def test(self):
    REG8(addr) = 0x08                         # ==> Error: "Cannot assign or delete this".
    (<volatile_uchar_ptr *>(addr))[0] = 0x08  # ==> OK.
```

When I use the inline function `REG8()`, I get the compiler error:
`Cannot assign or delete this`. However, the inserted code will work. I have no clue what is wrong here and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `[0]`:

```
REG8(addr)[0] = 0x08
```

You were assigning to a function call, not the value it points to.